# Qt Creator 3 for windows - KDiff build error

Tags: qt, qt-creator, kdiff3

I'm getting the following error message when building a project (KDiff3) in Qt Creator for Windows, any help would be appreciated.

> C:\kdiff3\src-QT4\kreplacements\kreplacements.h:27: 
>   error: QMainWindow: **No such file or directory**
>    #include < QMainWindow>

Answer (score 1):

When updating a QT project from QT4 to QT5 if you see the above error, you will need to edit your .pro file to include:

```
QT += widgets
```

[Transition from Qt 4.x to Qt5](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5)